# Array valued function to be called from type definition

Tags: fortran90, gfortran, fortran95

While writing a library to read image values, I have the following problem:
I defined a new type called `realimage`. Within this type a function is referenced, which returns an array as a result.

```
module typedefinition
implicit none

type realimage
  integer        :: byteorder     = 0
  contains
    procedure :: initialize => initializereal
    procedure :: pxvalues => pxvaluesreal ! Array valued function
end type realimage

contains
  function pxvaluesreal(this, x, y) result(val)
  implicit none
  type(realimage) this
  real val(5)
  integer :: x, y
  ...
  end function
end module
```

Compiling the module with gfortran and calling the function with `image1%pxvalues(x,y)`, I always get the following error message:

```
main.f95: In function ‘testtype’:
main.f95:15: internal compiler error
```

If I directly call the function in the main program `(pxvaluesreal(image1,x,y))`, everything works fine.

Is it possible to define the array dimension in the type definition in order to tell the compiler, which are the dimesions of the return value of the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internal compiler errors are always due to a compiler bug.  If you are using a recent version of gfortran you should consider reviewing their list of open bugs and perhaps filing a bug report.

Beyond that - your code is not standard compliant - the passed object 'this' must be polymorphic (declare it with CLASS rather than TYPE).  Otherwise your specification of the size of the array function result is correct - when you reference the pxvalues binding the compiler knows that the size of the function result is 5 as it 'knows' the interface of the specific procedure pxvaluesreal that the binding is associated with.